# Updating Form1 objects from Form2

Tags: c#, inheritance

I try to update Form1 values from Form2, but nothing happens. No errors also, strange...

Form1:

```
 public static Form2 f2{ get; set; } = new Form2();

 private void addButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            f2.Show(); 
        }
```

Form2:

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f1 = new Form();
        f1.label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Nothing happens. I can get data to my form2 from form1, but I cannot send, I mean I can, but nothing happens... Why? Thank you

Comment: With `Form f1 = new Form();` you are creating a new form instead of accessing one which is already open and you don't call `f1.Show();` therefore it will never be displayed.

Comment: So why can I access the label2 then? In other words, how can I change objects values in form1 from form2? How can I access the one that is open as you say? I am just trying to create an object and then access form1 data via it...

Comment: Form1 stays open, Form2 its just temporary, I dont want to open new form every time I do changes, I want to see them on old one

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you, if so please choose one, or answer with what you come up with

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions mentioned here would work for your specific case, but I encourage you to look at the big picture, and design a generalized solution that will work for most cases.

Your problem essentially boils down to ***doing something on one form based on the events of another form*.**

The best approach to do this is, in my opinion:

- Let `Form1` do all its own actions.
- Let `Form2` do all its own actions.
- If you need to do something on `Form1` based on an event that occurred on `Form2`, let `Form2` notify `Form1` that something happened there, so go do your own thing.
- If necessary, pass data from `Form2` to `Form1`.

So I would make use of [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) for this purpose.

Imagine you have a `Button` and a `Label` on your `Form1`. Clicking the button opens up `Form2`, on which you have another `Button`. Clicking this button on `Form2` should change the background color of the label on `Form1`. So our setup would look like this. You haven't mentioned if it's `Winforms` or `WPF`, so I'm using `WPF` for my convenience but the idea is the same in either.

### Form1

[image]

### Form2

[image]

In my `Form1` I'd declare a public delegate with a signature like this:

```
public delegate void NotifyEvent();
```

That is, this delegate represents a method that takes in no parameters, and has void return type. The idea is to let `Form2` 'call' a method in `Form1`, and that method essentially *notifies* the button was clicked on `Form2`. So, if there was a way for us to call a method that resides in the `Form1` from `Form2`, we can then notify `Form1` of an event happening on `Form2` With me so far?

Now, if I write a method like this in the `Form1`, and let it be called from `Form2`, that should accomplish our goal. Here, `lblDisp` is the `Label` in `Form1`.

```
public void ButtonClickedOnForm2()
{
    lblDisp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen);
}
```

To accomplish this, I would define a delegate of type `NotifyEvent` in `Form1` like below, and register the `ButtonClickedOnForm2()` method to it. Your `Form1` code behind should look like this

```
public delegate void NotifyEvent();

public partial class Form1 : Window
{
    public NotifyEvent notifyDelegate;

    Form2 form2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This is 'registering' the ButtonClickedOnForm2 method to the delegate.
        // So, when the delegate is invoked (called), this method gets executed.
        notifyDelegate += new NotifyEvent(ButtonClickedOnForm2);
    }

    public void ButtonClickedOnForm2()
    {
        lblDisp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen);
    }

    private void BtnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Passing the delegate to `Form2`
        form2 = new Form2(notifyDelegate);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Accordingly, now we need to modify our `Form2`. We need to tell us which delegate to invoke when the button click happens. So to do that, I'd pass the delegate in the constructor of `Form2` like so:

```
public partial class Form2 : Window
{
    NotifyEvent notifyDel;

    public Form2(NotifyEvent notify)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        notifyDel = notify;
    }

    private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This invokes the delegate, which in turn calls the ButtonClickedOnForm2 method in Form1.
        notifyDel.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Now, when the button is clicked on `Form2`, it invokes the delegate. And on our `Form1`, we've told it that in case the delegate is invoked, it should go ahead and execute the `ButtonClickedOnForm2` method. In that method, we've written code to change the background color of the label. And that should solve your problem.

---

### Passing Data

Additionally, if you want to pass data from `Form2` to `Form1`, you can simply add parameters to the delegate definition. Say you want to pass a `string` from `Form2` to `Form1`. Then, you'd change your delegate to look like this:

```
public delegate void NotifyEvent(string data);
```

And the method `ButtonClickedOnForm2` like so:

```
public void ButtonClickedOnForm2(string data)
{
    lblDisp.Content = data;
    lblDisp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen);
}
```

Then on `Form2`, invoke the delegate by passing a string like so:

```
private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This invokes the delegate, which in turn calls the ButtonClickedOnForm2 method in Form1.
    notifyDel.Invoke("I am from Form2");
}
```

Now clicking the button on `Form2` should change text and background color of label on `Form1` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `Form f1 = new Form();` you are creating a new form instead of accessing one which is already open and you don't call `f1.Show();` therefore it will never be displayed. You need a reference to the one which is open. E.g. pass form 1 as constructor parameter to form 2.

In form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _form1;

    public Form2 (Form1 from1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

In form 1:

```
// Cannot be static as we need a reference to `this`
private Form2 _f2;
public Form2 f2 {
    get {
        if (_f2 == null) {
            _f2 = new Form2(this);  // Pass form 1 as parameter to form 2.
        }
        return _f2;
    }
}

private void addButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    f2.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like that should work, you beat me to it so I'm not going to answer my own version of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for constructor idea. Anyway (this) does not work for me in global scope. So I needed to simplify it to this:

Form 2 with constructor:

```
  public Form1 _form1 { get; set; }
        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            _form1 = form1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form1.label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Form 1 creating new object with parameter everytime call needed(because of 'this'):

```
private void addButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    f2.Show();
}
```

Works fine so far...

Comment: Creating a new form every time seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

Form1:

```
private void addbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    f2.Show();
}


public void ColorChange()
{
    label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Form2:

```
public Form1 f1;

public Form2(Form1 m)
{
    this.f1 = m;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    f1.Show();
    f1.ColorChange();
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanation of why this code fixes the issue. Additionally - given the other descriptive answers - this could be improved by including some description of how this answer is different