# How to Inherit MainWindow in New Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

## New Class

I can inherit the `MainWindow` in a New `Class` using `MyClass : MainWindow`.

`combobox1` no longer needs to be `mainwindow.combobox1`.

```
public partial class MyClass : MainWindow
{
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
        if ((string)combobox1.SelectedItem == "red") 
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

---

## New Window

How can I inherit the `MainWindow` in a `New Window`?

I tried `NewWindow : Window : MainWindow` and `NewWindow : Window, MainWindow` but that is not the correct format.

Right now I have to pass the `MainWindow` to the `NewWindow`'s constructor.

`combobox1` has to be `mainwindow.combobox1`.

```
public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    MainWindow mainwindow;


    public NewWindow(MainWindow mainwindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.mainwindow = mainwindow;

        if ((string)mainwindow.combobox1.SelectedItem == "red") 
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make
`(string)mainwindow.combobox1.SelectedItem == "red"`
use
`(string)combobox1.SelectedItem == "red"`.

---

## MainWindow

Open New Window Button

```
private void btnOpenNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewWindow newwindow = new NewWindow(this);

    newwindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. What you really want to do is pass data and events between windows.

Comment: @Sach Should I inherit `MainWindow` for Classes?

Comment: Here's an answer I gave to a very similar question and it's applicable to your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161584/302248

Comment: You should make use of delegates and pass data and event occurrences between windows. That answer details every step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Form1 objects from Form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159697/updating-form1-objects-from-form2)

Comment: Does your main window have any XAML markup? Then you should not inherit from it in another .xaml.cs file because you will "override" its content.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your question would be this.

```
public partial class NewWindow : MainWindow 
{
   public NewWindow() : base()
   {
   }
   //usual Code 
}
```

> You inherit from MainWindow.

**Note:** But as mentioned in comments this is not suggested way.

Comment: Even then, the `: MainWindow` added to the class does not seem to remove the requirement for `mainwindow.combobox1`. It gives `object reference not set to instance of an object`. I must use `mainwindow.combobox1` instead of `combobox1`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention you also have to initialize components of parent class. here i did it by calling it's constructor.